Summation in a Case of Multivariate Lagrange Inversion
Background
In the proof of Theorem 9.1 pictured below (from these notes), a summation on $m$ appears in the line,
$$
[u^m]g(z,u)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}[u^{m-1}]P(z,u)^{m}.
$$
Each inner term resembles single-variable Lagrange inversion, i.e.,
$$
[u^m]g(u)=\frac{1}{m}[u^{m-1}]P(u)^{m},
$$
when $g=uP(g)$.
Question
From where does the summation on $m$ arise?


I believe I've figured out the issue. The summation appears too early in the proof, but let me change notation slightly to make clearer. We begin with $y=P(z,y)$, and we seek the coefficients of $y(z)$ in terms of $z$. To proceed, we introduce $u$ as in the original question and write,
$$
y = uP(z,y).
$$
By ordinary Lagrange inversion, we may write,
$$
[u^m]y(z,u) = \frac{1}{m}[y^{m-1}]P(z,y)^m.
$$
Multiplying by the indeterminate $u^m$ and summing over all values of $m$ tells us,
$$
y(z,u) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{m}[y^{m-1}]P(z,y)^m\right)u^m.
$$
Hence,
$$
f(z) = y(z,1) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}[y^{m-1}]P(z,y)^m,
$$
and thus,
$$
[z^n]f(z) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}[z^n y^{m-1}]P(z,y)^m,
$$
by the linearity of $[z^n]$.
